# Global Name 'q' not Defined - Python

Tags: python, nameerror

I have a program like :

```
class ABC:

    q = {}

    def update:
        self.state = (xx,xx)
        global q
        if self.state in q:
            // do something
```

I am getting the error :

> "NameError: global name 'q' is not defined"

Im new to python and need some help.

Comment: Your code is not valid python, so it is difficult to gauge what your intent is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`q` isn't being declared as a global variable here - it's being declared as a class variable of class `ABC`.

If you want `q` to be global, you should define it before you start declaring the class.

Answer (score 2):

You can move *q* outside of the class:

```
q = {}

class ABC: 

    def update:
        self.state = (xx,xx)
        global q
        if self.state in q:
            # do something
            pass
```

or you can reference *q* as a class variable:

```
class ABC:

    q = {}

    def update:
        self.state = (xx,xx)
        if self.state in ABC.q:
                # do something
                pass
```

Comment: ooh, Thanks Raymond, i think i get it. but why would i choose one over the other?